# Laravel 7. How to download a file from server (FTP)?

Tags: laravel, download, ftp, storage, disk

I created a disk in `config/filesystems.php` file

```php
'ftp' => [
    'driver' => 'ftp',
    'host' => 'ftp.domain.org',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'passive' => true,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'root' => '/',
    'url' => '/'
],
```

The connection is tested and works. On the server this file *exists*:

```php
$file_path = "/folder/aaa.txt";
```

But **I can't download it!** In the controller I wrote:

```php
$file = Storage::disk('ftp')->download($file_path);
return response()->download($file);
```

And this is the outcome:

> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException
> The file  "HTTP/1.0 200 OK  Cache-Control: no-cache, private
> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=aaa.txt  Content-Length: 0
> Content-Type: text/plain  Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 19:20:51 GMT"
> does not exist

**Additional issue**

Instead of downloading it, how do I display the same file in the browser? The following code does not work in this case:

```
return response()->file($file_path);
```

Comment: `Storage::download` is already a download response. You don't need a second one. Just do `return  Storage::disk('ftp')->download($file_path);`

Comment: Thank you very much @apokryfos! It works! I'm still inexperienced... sorry.

Comment: @apokryfos  Please plug this in as the answer.  Answers browse, search, and visualize better than comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `response()->download($file)` and `Storage::download($file)` will create a download response so you only need one of the two. Since your file is in remote storage you can just keep:

```
return  Storage::disk('ftp')->download($file_path);
```

You can also customise the filename and headers. You can also (probably) make the file show inline by doing:

```
return  Storage::disk('ftp')->download($file_path, 'any.txt', [
   'Content-Disposition' => 'inline'
]);
```

Comment: (or someone else) @apokryfos Could you take a look at my Additional issue, please?